# Web service Requesting a soap webservice fails vb.net soap web service wsdlsponse

Tags: vb.net, web, soap, service, wsdl

I have to call some services that provide a token at login with id and password. The token is not among the properties of the header. The type of request and response is custom. I write this code to pass the token in the header of the request, after get it from login response:

```
Public Sub New(token As String)
     MyBase.New
     Me.ttoken = token           
     Me.Url = Global.WILLAGENT2_2_2.My.MySettings.Default.WILLAGENT2_2_2_ana_AnagrafeService
     If (Me.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(Me.Url) = True) Then
         Me.UseDefaultCredentials = True
         Me.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = False
     Else
         Me.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = True
     End If
 End Sub

 Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal uri As Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
     Dim request As  HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
     'Dim urzi As New Uri("Https://us.creditonet.it:443/xxxxx")
     'Dim request As  System.Net.WebRequest = mybase.GetWebRequest(uri) 'gil
     request.Headers.Add("SecurityToken", ttoken)            
     ' request.Headers.Add("SecurityToken", ttoken)
     Dim soapEnvelopeXml As New  XmlDocument
     Dim stream As  Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
     soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream)
     Dim response  = request.GetRequestStream()
     Return request
End Function
```

But the code fails on:

```
Dim request As  HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
```

the code of the calls is:

```
Dim token As String
Dim dt As New LoginRequestDTO

dt.Login = Me.TxtId.Text.Trim
dt.Password = Me.TxtPwd.Text.Trim

token = service.Login(dt).SecurityToken.ToString
Dim ws2 As New ana.AnagrafeService(token)

Dim ws2request As New ana.RicercaCertificatiRequestDTO
Dim ws2result As ana.RicercaCertificatiDTO()
ws2request.CODICE_FISCALE = "DREDMN74E01A509B"
ws2request.CODICE_RITENUTA = "X45"
ws2request.ID_UTENTE = 33

ws2result = ws2.RicercaCertificati(ws2request)
```

where RicercaCertificatiDTO is a complex type.
THX

writing the GetWebRequest differently in the override the response fails .The error says:

> unable to cast dataset to datatable

I expect the request to work and the response to return an object of the expected type

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, as well as the missing aspects what's being called.   Specifically the bit related to the dataset that's involved.

Comment: I also wrote to pass the token in header of request:Public Sub New(token As String)
            MyBase.New
            Me.ttoken = token           
          End Sub
        Protected overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal uri As Uri ) As System.Net.WebRequest
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
            request.Headers.Add("SecurityToken", ttoken)            
                   Return request
        End Function

Comment: .the error returned on line 'Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)' is 'Unable to send content with this type of verb'

Comment: Not really too sure myself, but browsing your code I'm suspicious of `LoginRequestDTO`.  What exactly is that?  I'm guessing it's a dataset you're treating as datatable

Comment: UPDATE:The error is now on ws2result = ws2.RicercaCertificati(ws2request) and it is just 'impossible to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataSet' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.can you help me